# Import Carbon Powershell Module from shared folder

Tags: powershell, import, module

I use Powershell Remoting version 2.0.
I have downloaded the [Carbon](http://get-carbon.org/) Powershell Module. I copied it in shared folder:

**\SharedServer\PowershellModules\Carbon-1.0.0**

In my script ps1, I have this source code:

```
$PSPathCarbon = "\\SharedServer\PowershellModules\Carbon-1.0.0\Carbon"
. (Join-Path $PSPathCarbon Import-Carbon.ps1)
```

I get the following error:

> The term
>   '\SharedServer\PowershellModules\Carbon-1.0.0\Carbon\Import-Carbon.ps1'
>   is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Any suggestions about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
. (Join-Path $PSPathCarbon 'Import-Carbon.ps1')
```

Or:

```
. "$PSPathCarbon\Import-Carbon.ps1"
```

Comment: It says you need 64-bit version of powershell. Do you have that? When you run Test-Path "$PSPathCarbon\Import-Carbon.ps1" do you get true or false? Also try this <Import-Module Path\To\Carbon\Directory>